# Touch to stop momentum scroll also fires the tap event in Webviews

Tags: android, scroll, android-webview

If we do a momentum scroll in a webview, when we touch/tap the screen it stops the momentum scroll. But it also performs a click event in the webview content. I want to make the webview like this: during the momentum scroll, if the user tap the webview, it will only stop the scroll without triggering a click, and then in the second tap it will perform any click event on the webview content.

Can anyone suggest how can I do this?

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: @FirasDib , I could not find any solution yet, it seems this is the Default behavior of android webview. But could not find any workaround. You can use Google Chromium engine, that private API prevent the touches while performing momentum scrolling.

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed in Chrome m122, pending release Feb 20th 2024.

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1474135