# Tapping to stop momentum scroll on Chrome triggers a click event?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, mobile

On mobile browsers, when you're momentum scrolling, you can tap anywhere to stop the momentum scroll. On mobile Chrome (Android, iOS, and Win11 Chrome device mode), when I try to stop momentum scroll by tapping, it triggers the click event. Here's a Chromium bug report specifically for Webviews (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1474135) and an old SO questions also for Webviews ([Touch to stop momentum scroll also fires the tap event in webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51586395/touch-to-stop-momentum-scroll-also-fires-the-tap-event-in-webview)).

I'm encountering this on Chrome outside of Webviews as well, but only after a gesture. I.e. it occurs after I:

1. swipe back
2. start momentum scroll
3. tap to stop momentum scroll

Since that similar Chrome bugs have remain unresolved for years, I'd like to fix this using JS. Here's my attempt:

```
function chromeMomentumScrollHack() {
  const ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
  if (!ua.includes('chrome')
    || document.onscrollend === undefined) {
    return;
  }

  let isScrolling = false;
  window.addEventListener(
    'scroll',
    () => {
      isScrolling = true;
    },
    {
      capture: true,
      passive: true,
    },
  );
  window.addEventListener(
    'scrollend',
    () => {
      isScrolling = false;
    },
    {
      capture: true,
      passive: true,
    },
  );

  let lastCancelClickTime = -Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER;
  window.addEventListener(
    'pointerdown',
    () => {
      if (isScrolling) {
        lastCancelClickTime = performance.now();
      }
    },
    { capture: true },
  );
  window.addEventListener(
    'click',
    event => {
      if (performance.now() - lastCancelClickTime < 100) {
        event.preventDefault();
        event.stopPropagation();
      }
    },
    { capture: true },
  );
}
```

This works perfectly on mobile Chrome, but on desktop Chrome, it cancels too many clicks. The `scrollend` event triggers half a second after I stop scrolling, so if I click less than half a second after I stop scrolling, it cancels the click. Also, `scrollend` seems unreliable, it doesn't always trigger, so `isScrolling` gets stuck as `true`. Is there a better way to fix this issue?